# Significado de "descaderado"

Tags: definiciones

El contexto:

> P----- camina como travesti descaderado. ¿Cómo poronga consiguió seducir a la diosa del tango?

La frase aparece como un comentario a [este video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jTeVa7NCoTk). El que lo escribió presumiblemente habla español de Argentina.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

De [clayla.com.ar](http://www.clayla.com.ar/displasia.htm):

> Es muy común escuchar que los perros de edad avanzada se “descaderan”. El término **descaderado** hace referencia popularmente a la displasia y si nos referimos a animales de edad avanzada, en la mayoría de los casos no es la cadera la responsable de este problema, sino que se trata de afecciones de la columna dorsal o lumbar, mostrando grandes dificultades de desplazamiento y hasta paresias del tren posterior.

Los perros descaderados se mueven poco, tienen problemas para incorporarse, se tambalean y en general son menos activos. El que escribió el comentario critica la forma de bailar de P---- comparándolo con un "perro descaderado", probablemente refiriéndose a que sus movimientos son rígidos y no tienen ninguna gracia.

Comment: Si lo intento de manera critica. Buscaba la definicion. Gracias por darmela. Este termino se usa fuera de la Argentina? Sorprende que no este en la RAE.

Comment: Yo no lo había escuchado nunca en España, ni lo habría entendido salvo por lo que se pueda deducir.

Comment: `cadeira` en portugués significa silla .. es interesante q crees q es nu frase de eso parte de america del sur.

Comment: @roberto no entiendo muy bien qué quieres decir, ni cómo se relaciona "cadeira" con la pregunta. El comentario es evidentemente de América del Sur: está escrito en castellano y desde luego no es español de España.

Comment: @Yay  - By circumstance I happened to run into this question in an RSS feed before coming here, and from reading the title and noting just the word I mistook it for a Portuguese word. I looked it up in priberam online dictionary and it suggested it was a typo for "descadeirado" — which is actually the same meaning as the spanish word here. the root of this word is **cadeira**. The language transmission from Brazil especially to Uruguay and Argentina are pertinant to zadrozny's original speculation in the question.

Comment: @robertotomás How would you translate this? Something like, 'a tranny with a spinal injury'?